# A conclusion from Aubin-Lions lemma

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose that $u\in L^{\infty}(0,T;H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\cap H^{2}(\Omega))$, and $u_{t}\in L^{\infty}(0,T;H_{0}^{1}(\Omega))$. Can we say from  Aubin-Lions lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin%E2%80%93Lions_lemma) that 
$$
u\in C(0,T;H_{0}^{1}(\Omega))\quad\&\quad u_{t}\in C(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regularity $u_t \in L^\infty(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$ directly yields $u \in C(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$ (just integrate over $t$). You do not even need Aubin-Lions.

However, you cannot achieve $u_t \in C(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ under your requirements: Take $\varphi \in C^{0,1}([0,T])$, such that $\varphi$ is weakly differentiable, but $\varphi' \not\in C([0,T])$. For arbitrary $\psi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ consider
$$u(t,x) = \varphi(t) \, \psi(x).$$

Comment: So, if we have $u_{tt}\in L^{\infty}\big(0,T; L^{2}(\Omega)\big)$ then $u_{t}\in C\big(0,T; L^{2}(\Omega)\big)$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. By Aubin-Lions, something like $u_t \in L^\infty(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$ and $u_{tt} \in L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(\Omega))$ should be enough.